# If list contains an item, then list equals to item

Tags: python, list

I don't know how to formulate the question correctly:
I have a list of lists, which contains multiple items.

```
mylist=[['a','b','c','₾'],['x','t','f','₾'],['a','d'],['r','y'],['c','₾'],['a','b','c','i'],['h','j','l','₾']]
```

If any of the lists contains symbol '₾', I want to append the symbol to another list, else append None.

```
result=[]
for row in mylist:
    for i in row:
        if i=='₾':
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(None)
result
```

But I want to get this result :

```
result=['₾','₾',None,None,'₾',None,'₾']
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
result = ['₾' if '₾' in sublist else None for sublist in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for row in mylist:
    if '₾' in row:
        result.append('₾')
    else:
        result.append(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mylist=[['a','b','c','₾'],['x','t','f','₾'],['a','d'],['r','y'],['c','₾'],['a','b','c','i'],['h','j','l','₾']]
>>> c = '₾'
>>> [c if c in row else None for row in mylist]
['₾', '₾', None, None, '₾', None, '₾']
```

That is, you can use a list comprehension: for each list in `mylist`,
use ₾ if it is in the list, or else `None`:

```
c = '₾'
result = [c if c in row else None for row in mylist]
```

There were several problems with the loop in the posted code:

- After finding a ₾, the inner loop should break, stop searching the rest
- The value should only be `None` when all values were not ₾

Here's one way to fix the loop:

```
result = []
for row in mylist:
    for item in row:
        if item == '₾':
            result.append(item)
            break
    else:
        result.append(None)
```

Notice here that `else` belongs to the inner `for`, not the `if`.
The meaning of this is that if the inner loop never reached a `break`,
then this `else` will be executed.
This fixes both of the problems I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

A small edit to your code can be done to get the desired result

```
mylist=[['a','b','c','₾'],['x','t','f','₾'],['a','d'],['r','y'],['c','₾'],['a','b','c','i'],['h','j','l','₾']]

result=[]
for row in mylist:
    if '₾' in row:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        result.append(None)
result
```

Output

```
['₾', '₾', None, None, '₾', None, '₾']
```

The above code can be reduced into a line of List Comprehension

```
['₾' if '₾' in row else None for row in mylist]
```